# Why is my AWS Dynamo Lambda function returning null or timing out completely?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using an AWS DynamoDB to store a string associated with a user. [Photo of my dynamoDb table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FhbO.png).

In my lambda function, I have the partition key (username) and I am trying to get the string that is associated with the username. It is returning null and not even getting to my console.log instruction.

```
//I don't think you need to see the top part, I'm showing it just in case

let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
exports.handler = async function(event){
    let username = 'adminDebug'; //test parameter
    return await listSongs();
}



async function listSongs(){
    var params = {
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
       ":v1": {
         S: "adminDebug"
        }
      }, 
      KeyConditionExpression: "username = :v1", 
      TableName: "name_of_my_table"
    };
    
    console.log("about to launch"); //appears before the null return
    dynamo.query(params, (err, data)=>{
        console.log("function has returned"); //does NOT fire off before query ends
        if(err){
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else return data;
    });
}
```

I have also tried to do this with promises like so

```
//main snippet
return await listSongs();

async function listSongs()
     return dynamo.query(params).promise();
```

and that will make it throw an error  `"errorMessage": "2022-08-21T16:24:17.5Z 9740-720-48a3e-5b0d0e Task timed out after 3.01 seconds"`

Additional notes:

- My lambda has the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess role
- My db does not have a sort-key. I just want to link a string to a primary-key.
- I am using query() because getItem() requires me to have a sort-key.
- I am using the AWS lambda web-app to code this.
- Lambda is hooked up to an API gw but for testing, I am using the standard 'test' feature.

Thank you so much for your help. I wouldn't ask if I hadn't spent 3+ hours on this already.

Comment: I am just looking for a way to have CRUD operations on a list of usernames linked to strings. I am using DynamoDB because the web-client I write my code in does not allow me to use a MySQL library. As far as I know, DynamoDB is the best solution for me in this context.

Comment: If you configured the Lambda function to attach to a VPC then don't (unless you strictly need to, then attach it to a private subnet and ensure outbound network path to the internet via NAT and IGW or to the DynamoDB service via VPC Endpoint).

Comment: Also, your first variant of the code won't work, regardless of the network connectivity issue. Specifically it will not return the items. Use the latter form with async/await.

Comment: @jarmod THAT WAS IT! THANK YOU I FORGOT I DID THAT WHEN TRYING TO SET UP MYSQL. IT'S BEEN HOURS! I WOULD HAVE NEVER GUESSED THAT WAS THE ISSUE!

Answer (score 1):

A common reason for AWS Lambda functions to time out is that the function makes an outbound network request e.g. to a website or to an AWS service such as DynamoDB or S3 but the Lambda function has no network route to the internet or to an AWS service endpoint. The attempt to connect then fails after a certain timeout or after 3 seconds when the Lambda service times out the Lambda function (because the default timeout is 3 seconds).

This typically happens because the Lambda function was incorrectly configured to attach to a VPC.

If you don't need the Lambda function in a VPC, then don't configure it to attach to any VPC.

If you do need to attach to a VPC, then attach it to a private subnet (specifically *not* a public subnet) and ensure an outbound network path to the internet via a route table to a NAT device/gateway and IGW. Alternatively, if your connection is to an AWS service only then you can add a VPC Endpoint.